# Take value from a person or group column in a list and insert it into another list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate, flow, person-or-group

I have a list that includes a person/group column, and I'd like to set up a flow to extract that value and insert it into a similar column in a different list.

Is this possible?

Not quite sure what operators to select.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can copy person/group column value from one list to another list.

1. When configuring the "create item" action, you need to click on `Enter custom value` in the person or group column.

   [image]
2. This will expose Dynamic properties.
3. Select the person or group column "claims" entry in Dynamic properties.

   [image]

**Reference**: [Copy Person from 1 List to Another List](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Copy-Person-from-1-List-to-Another-List/td-p/212587)

Comment: genius, thank you so much!

Comment: Great, glad it helped you. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.